# c# connection string and concatenation app.config

Tags: c#, connection-string, app-config

I have the following connection string through which i connect to an Access database(.mdb) located in a sub-folder inside the root-folder of my application :

```
 OleDbConnection con = new OledbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory() + "Data\rctts.mdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=mypassword;")
```

My question is, how do i put the connection string in the app.config file? Generally, i use :

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The issue i am facing is that in my connection string, i am doing some concatenations and also using `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()` to set the `Data Source`...
How do i do the same concatenation in app.config ? Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: That looks like VB.Net concatenation, not C#.

Comment: @juharr , now it looks like c# :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\rctts.mdb;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;Integrated Security=True"
```

and then try to set the value of `DataDirectory` as below:

```
var currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
var basePath = currentDomain.BaseDirectory;
currentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", basePath+"\Data");
```

at the corresponding startup file of your application.

Comment: don't mind me asking, i don't see the app.config part here?

Comment: The app config part is the first one. In the app config you would just replace "Data Source=..." with the above.

Comment: can you explain what `|Data Directory|` means here? is it working like a variable which is expecting values?

Comment: @zackraiyan Exactly ! It is variable that can be set trough AppDomain. Please check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/08/26/working-with-local-databases/

Comment: That's pretty cool! It looks like MS added some "smarts" to the code interpreting connection strings to address this specific problem. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Why am i getting : `Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference`?

Comment: @zackraiyan Generally this problem is described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc30469. Please give a go to the update answer and let me know. However, I don't think that the problem relies in these two lines.

Comment: your answer is still not perfect, take a look at the connectionstring in app.config and also what you set from code

Comment: @zackraiyan could you please share the line where this error happens ?

Comment: in the `AppDomain.SetData` line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172089/discussion-between-christos-and-zack-raiyan).

Comment: never mind me asking, i don't see the use of `name` of the connection string anywehre in your code ?? is it normal ?

Comment: @zackraiyan You don't have to use the connection string here. You just declare and set a variable at the startup of your application. Then whenever you try to read the connection string, the value of `|DataDirectory|` will be replaced with this value. Hence it is not needed.

Comment: @Christos , understood

Answer (score 3):

Although configuration APIs offer no facilities to manipulate connection strings for you, you could place connection string "template" into configuration, and do the rest of manipulation in your code using `string.Format`:

Config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source={0}Data\rctts.mdb;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

C# code:

```
string conStr = string.Format(
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString
,   System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory()
);
```

Comment: i am getting a warning : `Runtime error may occur when converting 'ConnectionStringSetting' to 'IFormatProvider'` , should i be worried?

Comment: @zackraiyan That's right - I forgot to add `.ConnectionString`. That's what happens when I do not try to compile things locally. Thank you!